# Check return value for if-statement

Tags: java, null, hashmap, boolean

I'm trying to make a bit of code that returns a boolean value depending on whether an item was successfully removed from a HashMap or not.

My understanding is that map.remove(Key) should return the Key if it worked and null if not. My approach was to check if the return value is null and print false if it is, true if anything else.

The problem I'm having comes from that I don't know how to check what the return value was inside my method.

Here is my attempt so far.

```
public boolean deleteMapEntry(String entry)
{
    testMap.remove(entry);
    if(null)
    {
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
       return true;
    }
 }
```

Obviously saying if (null) doesn't work, but I can't find what would.

Comment: Do you mean you want `if(remove(entry) == null)`?

Comment: Note that `remove` will return the value, not the key .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the value of `testMap.remove(entry)` to a variable to test it to see if it is null...

```
String value = testMap.remove(entry);
return value != null;
```

you can also just test what you remove directly and not use a variable:

```
return testMap.remove(entry) != null;
```